# How very high frequencies (VHF) are propagated during night over large distances?

Tags: radio, propagation, vhf

I am new in telecomunications and this question just came up today and I coudn't find an explanation.

Here is the most common model for the ionosphere:

[image]

The ionosphere layer E is the main resposible for the reflection of the VHF signal which will allow communication over long distances during the day. But, during night, we don't have E layer because of the absence of the sun.

So, how does it happens during night?
Does F2 layer became the main responsible for the reflection of the VHF signals?

Comment: It's typically for HF we talk about ionospheric refractions, not VHF. (Though that is also possible)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, at night, you simply don't get long-range propagation of VHF signals at all, unless you bounce them off of something else, such as a satellite or the moon — or even ionized meteor trails.

I would recommend directing any followup questions to [Amateur Radio.SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/). Those people have more direct experience in this area.